# Acknowledge startup funding in manucript

Tags: publications

Has anyone acknowledged their own university for startup funding that was used to conduct the research to be published in an article? If so could you please share the wordings that you used? Thanks!

Comment: It is polite, but probably not necessary to do this. But generally, acknowledging help of any kind is good.

Comment: If your university specifies the wording that should be used, then use that. If they don't then just write something. There's no magical One True Sentence ;-)

Comment: Do you know where your startup funds came from? Sometimes there may be a more specific source that is worth crediting.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you were given other specific instructions from your university, all you need to do by way of acknowledgement is to put “[name of author], [name of university]” on the title page of your paper. This is enough to ensure that people understand that the university is paying your salary, giving you an office, and providing you with any other resources that you need to do your job, including startup funding if applicable.